# What is the scale of the CPU utilisation for f1-micro on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The instance details of my f1-micro instance shows a graph of CPU utilisation fluctuating between 8% and 15%, but what is the scale? The f1-micro has 0.2 CPU so is my max 20%? Or does the 100% in the graph mark my 20% of the CPU? Occasionally the graph has gone above 20% but is it bursting then? Or does the bursting start at 100% in the graph?

The recommendation to increase performance is always displayed. Is it just sales tactics? The VM is a watchdog so it is not doing much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to build up a small test in order to answer your question and if interested you can do the same to double check.

### TEST

I created two instances one `f1-micro` and one `n1-standard-1` and then I forced a CPU burst making use of [stress](https://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server), but you can use any tool of your choice.

```
$ sudo apt-get install stress
$ stress --cpu 1 & top
```

In this way we can compare the output of `top` of the two instances with the one showed in the dashboard, since the operating system is not aware to share the CPU so we expect a 100% seen from the inside of the machine.

### RESULTS

While the output of `top` for both the instances showed as expected that the 99.9% of the CPU was currently used, the output of the dashboard is more interesting.

- `n1-standard-1` showed a stable value around 100% the whole time.
- `f1-micro shows` an initial spike to 250% (because it is using a bigger share of the CPU assigned, i.e. it is running on bursting mode) and then it reduces to 100%.

I repeated the test several times and each time I got the same behaviour, therefore the `%` refers to the share of CPU that you are currently using.

This features is Documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types):

> "f1-micro machine types offer bursting capabilities that allow instances to use additional physical CPU for short periods of time. Bursting happens automatically when your instance requires more physical CPU than originally allocated"

On the other hand if you want to know more about those recommendation and how they work you can check the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances?hl=en_US&_ga=2.97095064.-662560920.1515668404#using_the_monitoring_agent_for_more_precise_recommendations).

Comment: Thank you! You took a scientific approach: prepare a test and evaluate the results. Very good! I just tried to look up the answer..

Comment: By the way right now my instance is doing nothing since yesterday, i.e. CPU 2% from top and I visualise the recommendation to upgrade the size of the machine. This is due to the way the recommendation are implemented, checking both the burst periods and average load.
By the way if you found my answer helpful consider to accept it and upvote it.